# NodeJS Managed VM receiving 403 on datastore writes

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-node, managed-vm

Dear Google Team & GAE Enthusiasts:

I tried deploying my NodeJS app to my GAE project with the new remote dockerless option: 
"gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --set-default --remote"
The deployment process seemed to be fine -- meaning no errors occurred while deploying.

After the deployment was performed, Interestingly all my GET requests that read data from the datastore are successful.

However, when I try to POST right when the data is supposed to be written to the datastore, I keep receiving the 'Forbidden' 403 error code.

This is very weird and awkward and puzzling since when I run my node app on my localhost, I am able to read/store to my datastore cloud instance without issues.

I guess my question is if anyone else is facing this same issue at the moment and how was it resolved?

FYI, last week I tried doing datastore access (read & write) from a NodeJS managed VM and it worked. I followed the [Bookshelf example](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-structured-data)

I re-deployed the same example today and it failed on all POSTs dealing with datastore writes as well.

I already opened similar tickets here:

- [gcloud-node github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node/issues/783)
- [gcloud github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud/issues/31)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using the REST api directly? Or are you using the gcloud-node library? 403 is usually a authentication / permission error in my experience. How are you authenticating?

Comment: I am using the gcloud-node. on my localhost I have full authentication and can add stuff to the cloud datastore. However, on the managed vm in GCE it fails. I'm currently trying to do the service account route though I should not need to go this route.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to follow up on this since I found the solution to my issue.
Pretty much, I had to pass datastore authorization based on the explanations indicated below:
[gcloud-node-js](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/authorization)

BTW, the links above provide a history of the bug tracked by the Google team if it ever gets resolved.